# Google Places - Autocomplete box - Bring suggestions to foreground

Tags: api, maps

I have an application where I'm using a Ajax Modal Pop Up extender to allow a user to add a new user and map them to a location using the Google Places Autocomplete box.

Used something suggested here:
http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.in/2011/12/aspnet-google-map-version-3-in-aspnet.html

My problem is that when I use this on a normal page, the suggestions appear correctly, but on a modal pop up extender they appear in the background. I want to bring this to the foreground. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but it should work.

```
//Have to do this or else the autocomplete list is hidden under the popup window
    var pacContainerInitialized = false;
    $('#autocompleteMapSearch').keypress(function () {
        if (!pacContainerInitialized) {
            $('.pac-container').css('z-index', '9999');
            pacContainerInitialized = true;
        }
    });
```